# Testing row by row for equality in two columns (factor/character data)

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr, levels

I am trying to test for equality in two columns, per row. However, my data is not numeric. The data set I am working with was merged from two data sets. Going through the data I noticed that columns that should be identical are actually different. This is an extremely large data set (approx 300K obs) so I am trying to code.

E.g. Source.x is from the 1st data set in the merge function and Source.y is from the 2nd data set in the merge function.

```
RightID   Source.x    Source.y
1000      Ground      Unnamed Stream
1001      Ground      Ground
1002      Stream      Stream
1003      Bear Creek  Ground
```

I would like to return a new data frame just containing observations 1000 and 1003 since these. I have tried the following code...

```
lapply(rights, rights$Source.x == rights$Source.y
filter(rights, rights$Source.x == rights$Source.y
filter(rights, identical(Source.x, Source.y)
```

However, because the data is in factor/character format and have different levels due to the variability in the source name, none of my code has managed to work. Source.x has 6743 levels and Source.y has 6457. As far as I can tell, there is no posted solution to my issue that elaborates on this levels issue. If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: To avoid factors, you can use the options `stringsAsFactors = F` when you read your data, or if you use `dplyr`, you can use `data_frame` which keep the string column as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`levels <- sort(unique(unlist(rights[, c('source.x', 'source.y')])))
rights$source.x <- factor(rights$source.x, levels = levels)
rights$source.y <- factor(rights$source.y, levels = levels)
result <- rights[rights$source.x == rights$source.y, ]`

You can specify the levels for each of the factors so that they are consistent. Just create a unique list of levels using both columns.

Comment: Hi @troh, thank you for your input. The code ran just fine but results yielded an empty data frame with 286 K rows (equivalent to the # of rows in the rights data base). Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer. `==` is probably what you want to use instead of `identical`